# Navigating to login page on getting status 401 using interceptors in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, http, ionic2

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, Headers, RequestOptions, Request, Response, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class SecureHttpService extends Http {

  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    // return super.request(url, options);
    return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchErrors());
  }

   private catchErrors() {
    return (res: Response) => {
      if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
          //nav.push(loginPage); I want to do something like this if status is 401
        debugger;
      }
      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }
```

I am trying to navigate to login page when there is 401 error status, but as ionic does not allow services to be used inside a service. How can this be achieved?

app.module.ts :-

```
 providers: [
{
    provide: Http,
    useFactory: (backend:XHRBackend, defaultOptions:RequestOptions) => {
        return new SecureHttpService(backend, defaultOptions);
    },
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
},
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `app.component.ts` or your first page for that matter:

```
  import { NavController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';

  constructor(navCtrl: NavController, events: Events) {
      this.events.subscribe('http:forbidden', error => {
          this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage, {errorMessage: error});
      });
  }
```

Now you can just emit from your service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, Headers, RequestOptions, Request, Response, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class SecureHttpService extends Http {

  constructor(public events: Events, backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    // return super.request(url, options);
    return super.request(url, options).catch(this.catchErrors());
  }

   private catchErrors() {
    return (res: Response) => {
      if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
          // will trigger the event defined earlier which did have access to the NavController
          this.events.publish('http:forbidden', "Something went wrong.");
        debugger;
      }
      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }
```

Comment: I have already done this, my interceptor is running. All I want to do is navigate to login page on error status 401, but as I am not able to use navcontroller inside my service, how can I setroot to login page

Comment: Ah I see, currently on my phone but look into ionics `Events`, allows you to emit from your service and listen for that event in f.e. the app.component (so it always executes) where you can use the NavController

Comment: Event service is also not working, it is saying can not read `publish` of undefined.    `private catchErrors() {
    return (res: Response) => {
      if (res.status === 401 || res.status === 403) {
          this.ev.publish('setRoot', this.name);
          // this.navCtrl.push(HomePage); 
      }
      return Observable.throw(res);
    };
  }`

Comment: sadly no :(. I am not able to use any service inside this component. Will find another way to use interceptors in ionic 2.

Answer (score 0):

@Utkarsh Prakash I had this same issue, I am using an interceptor to push my oAuth token into the auth header on each http request.  I then wanted to use the same interceptor to detect a 401 on response from my api and then show my login page.  Since I dont see any interceptor in the above (as in `implements HttpInterceptor`) let me post my code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private tokenStorage: TokenStorage, private events: Events) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return this.tokenStorage.getTokenObservable().mergeMap((token: Token) => {
            // add the Bearer token to the header
            if (token != null) {
                request = request.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token.access_token}`
                    }
                });
            }
            return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                // do something with the response if you want to
            }, (err: any) => {
                // we are interested on error
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    if (err.status === 401) {
                        this.events.publish('http:forbidden', "Session Expired");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

the important part here as detailed above by @Ivaro18 is the raising of the event on (in my case) the 401.  I then added the following in my HomePage equivalent:

```
constructor(events: Events, navigation: NavController) {
    // watch for unauth
    events.subscribe('http:forbidden', error => {
        navigation.push(LoginPage, {errorMessage: error});
    });
}
```

then when any http call returned a 401 my app displays the Login Page